# Does websockets works only with safari browser?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, safari

I trying to implement chat application using websockets.But the problem is ,  it is working only with safari 5. When am trying to execute in Firefox v14 or Chrome v21 ,am getting the error "Unsupported Websocket version: 13".I think these versions of Firefox and Chrome supports Websockets but i dont know to eliminate that error.
 http://angelozerr.wordpress.com/2011/07/23/websockets_jetty_step1/ From this URL i wrote source code chat App.

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Safari 5 supports only a legacy draft version of WebSocket. All of the current versions of the other browsers (including safari 6) support the final RFC 6455 version (which is version 13). It is likely that the websocket server that you are using only supports draft spec clients. You may need to upgrade to the latest version of your server software/library or otherwise double check that your websocket server supports RFC6455.

Comment: Thanks for Ur response . U know Firefox v14 or  Chrome v21 supporting Web sockets but i dont know why application is not running otherthan safari or opera new verssions....If possible refer me upgraded versions of Websocket server